# Streaming uploading csv file to database (leveldb)

Tags: database, node.js, csv, file-upload

I am writing a little application and am stuck at the part where I want to upload a .csv file and store the entries into my database. I use the express framework and played around with multipart / busboy and formidable. I succeeded in uploading the file and saving it on the the server. I could now just extract the data and delete it again, but I thought with Node.js the nicer approach would be to convert each line to a database object and store it on the fly without ever saving the whole file on the server. I found some examples for file uploads but no imminent conversion to objects / storage to a database. Maybe could you help me out?

Below you see what is called upon a "post" request for the upload-route.

```
exports.uploadTradesProcess = function (req,res) {
  var form = new multiparty.Form();
  form.onPart = function(part) {
  }
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('received upload:\n\n');
    res.end(util.inspect({fields:fields, files:files}))
  });
  return;
}
```

The "form.onPart" line doesn't do anything yet. I was wondering whether I could make the upload being cut into chunks / parts with every new line within the uploaded file...

Here is the template for the database entries:

```
var Trade = new dulcimer.Model({
  date: {type: 'integer'},
  exchange: {type: 'string'},
  currency1: {type: 'string'},
  amount1: {type: 'numeric'},
  currency2: {type: 'string'},
  amount2: {type: 'numeric'},
  exchangerate: { derive: function() {
    return this.currency1/this.currency2; } } }, {db: db, name: 'trade'});
```

This is my first post to stackoverflow and I hope it is not too long or too unspecific and would appreciate your feedback. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would also be interested in an answer to this...